# How to see iCloud Key-Value Data

Tags: ios, icloud

I know that Apple have:
https://developer.icloud.com/
for looking UIDocument in iCloud.

But is there any tool for looking  Key-Value Data that is stored in iCloud ?

I have integrated saving to iCloud and now am doing some testing.